# Call to a member function fetchAll() on MYSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute stored procedure, i want to have output as an associative array, but i am getting following error.

> Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean

and following is my PHP script which is calling the procedure

```
        $query_text = "CALL procedure1(?,?,@mobNum,@firstInsert);";
        $output=$this->pdo->prepare($query_text);
        $output=$output->execute(array($number,$code));
print_r($output->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Comment: the error tells you, that the query didn't work and therefor your `$output` is false.

Comment: the error still tells you the same: the fetch crashes cause you try to fetch something where the query didn't work. `$output` is false and not a mysql result. You should either catch that or check why the query doesn't work.

Comment: how many parameters have your function `procedure1` ? 2 or 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `procedure1` has 4 parameters you should:

```
$query_text = "CALL procedure1(?,?, @mobNum, @firstInsert);";
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($query_text);
$stmt->bindParam(1,$number);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$code);
$result = $stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

If just 2 change first line to `$query_text = "CALL procedure1(?,?);";` then.

**EDIT** If you still ahve your error, try to handle sql error:

```
if ($result) {
    print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
} else {
    echo "\nPDOStatement::errorInfo():\n";
    $arr = $stmt->errorInfo();
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: i Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on null this is what i am getting now

Comment: Check updated answer. you should `$stmt->fetchAll()` not `$result->fetchAll()`